Map Shift+Alt+Period
emacs uses shift + alt + > and shift + alt + < for home and end (Note < > are the same as , . since shift is pressed anyways). Is there a way to map this in vim?
This doesn't seem to work:
nnoremap <S-A-.> gg
nnoremap <S-A-,> G


nnoremap <M->> G
nnoremap <M-<> gg

